# So if I could shout in space, no one can ever hear me including myself?

Tags: sound

I was just googling on how does radio waves travel in space and stumbled upon this reddit post [If sound can't travel through space, how can radio waves?](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1r15bm/if_sound_cant_travel_through_space_how_can_radio/) and the idea that sound can't travel in space caught my attention.

Although it makes absolute sense that sound needs medium to travel from one end to another, has this actually been tested in space somehow? if "theoratically" I was able to shout in a void space would I look like this dog?

I still have my doubts.

Comment: If a tree falls in space...

Comment: For the _including myself_ part, see [Could you hear the sound of your own body in the vacuum of space?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/12992/49) Otherwise, and while this would likely be a question better fit for [physics.se] and has no [space.se] application, you wouldn't hear yourself shout because you wouldn't be able to produce any deliberate sound as the air left in your body that's now exposed to vacuum [rushes out at the speed of sound](http://www.geoffreylandis.com/higgins.html). It would cause vibrations of your body, interpreted as sound by your inner ear as a short "pop" tho.

Comment: Mind that being suddenly exposed to vacuum of space would be a rather painful experience far less pleasant than someone punching you in your celiac plexus (abdomen). You'll have far greater problems than not hearing yourself shout, and [about 10 seconds left to hear yourself think](http://www.geoffreylandis.com/vacuum.html) and find a way out of the unfortunate situation you're in.

Comment: Also related (answering why you wouldn't be able to produce coherent, deliberate sound with your vocal cords and "shout"): [Would a woodwind instrument still play in outer space?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/12999/49)

Comment: @TildalWave I probably should've constructed the question differently, but what i'm really interested to know is that for example if astronats were in a spacecraft and something exploded close to them without affecting the spacecraft itself would they not hear anything?

Comment: @razzak Only as the debris produced by the explosion start hitting the station.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't shout without air to expel from your lungs, so presumably you're in a space suit with air in it. Therefore you can hear yourself shout just fine. (Even if you didn't have a helmet's worth of air around your head, you'd hear the shout via vibration through your own body.)

The vibrations in the air, that make up the sound of your shout, would vibrate your helmet as well. If your helmet was touching another astronaut's helmet, that would conduct sound reasonably well, and that astronaut could hear you.

Another astronaut floating in space next to you wouldn't hear a thing, because there's no medium to conduct vibrations between you and them.

I don't know if astronauts have done this experiment; I'm sure the equivalent has been done in vacuum chambers on Earth.